# Get all kubernetes pods ip by ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: kubernetes

I've an ASP.NET Core Web API deployed on kubernetes via DevOps.
I have 4 pods.

Now, inside my API, I have a method that clear zentity framework plus cache, but when I call it using postman it is executed obviously only on called pod.

I'd like that when I call clear cache API on a pod, it collect all pods ip and recall clear cache API on every pod.

Can I collect pods ip inside the API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the Pods' IP addresses by using the official k8s C# client. You will also need relevant `Role`, `RoleBinding` and `ServiceAccount` to access the cluster's kube-apiserver.

```cs
using k8s;

namespace simple
{
    internal class PodList
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Load from the default kubeconfig on the machine (for local testing).
            var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigFile();

            // Load from in-cluster configuration (for production)
            // var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.InClusterConfig()

            IKubernetes client = new Kubernetes(config);
            
            var selector = "app=abc";
            var list = client.CoreV1.ListNamespacedPod("default", labelSelector: selector, pretty: true);
            foreach (var item in list.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Status.PodIP);
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

Check out these links:

- [C# SDK for k8s](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp)
- [RBAC Authorizations](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp)
- [Example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/blob/master/examples/simple/PodList.cs)